# How to animate this fluid flow over airfoil?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation, fluid-dynamics

I found this website very interesting "http://bugman123.com/FluidMotion/index.html" here he provided various animations of fluid flow and some codes are given in Mathematica. I found this animation of fluid flow over airfoil very interesting.
[image]

Kindly anyone provide Mathematica code for the animation of flow over the airfoil similar to the image shown.

I have no clue how to get to the above image. So far I got this flow over a flat plate. I used conformal mapping to get this image, Still, trying to animate the change in streamlines with the angle in the flow angle.

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]]
z1 = x1 + I*y1; 
z2 = Refine[ComplexExpand[0.5*(z1 + Sqrt[-4 + z1^2])], Element[{x1, y1}, Reals]]; 
z3 = Refine[ComplexExpand[z2*E^(I*theta)], Element[{x1, y1, theta}, Reals]]; 
z4 = Refine[ComplexExpand[z3/1 + 1/z3], Element[{x1, y1, theta}, Reals]]; 
U = 100; 
fz4 = U*z4; 
theta = Pi/3; 
ψ4[x1_, y1_] = Refine[ComplexExpand[Im[fz4]], Element[{x1, y1}, Reals]]; 
con = 
  ContourPlot[ψ4[x1, y1], {x1, -5, 0}, {y1, -5, 5}, 
    Contours -> 10*Table[i, {i, -100, 100, 4}]]
```

I agree that my work might be way off the track. I'm just started learning Mathematica. I will edit as my work progress.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: hi, I update the question with what I have done.

Comment: Post the code you tried not the resulting image.

Comment: `ImageTransformation` may be useful.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late update. I have included my code.

Comment: These are beautiful pictures, but it is not suitable for visualizing the flow. Actually, there are no such cells. This is just confusing.

Comment: hi, there is a video in the link that I provided in that link there is a video under the name - "Joukowski Airfoil - C++, 11/8/07" showing moving flow

Comment: hi, I upvote the question with interest

Comment: perhaps this article can help https://complex-analysis.com/content/joukowsky_airfoil.html#mjx-eqn-jouk

Comment: @cmarangu , Thanks , that material in that link seems super